# Internal keyboard not detected

Tags: keyboard

On my netbook (Acer Aspire One - zg5 - aoa150) Xubuntu 16.04 sometimes fails to find internal keyboard and/or touchpad. Restarting mostly helps, but its annoying. How can i force the keyboard and touchpad to work every time?

Comment: Is it broken at the login screen so you can't type your password or after the login screen?

Comment: I have automatic login so i dont know. Will try, its hard to catch.

Comment: Wont let me change the need for password in civilized way, but thats is separate issue. Know of some script to test for every piece of hardware and set it permanently in some file, so the system tries to find it all repeatedly and wont accept alternatives? Something like WinXP used to do?